# How to use a Mock Api in android?

Tags: android

i'm a beginner in Android and i'm trying to make an application for properties. i want to use this example of a mock api with OKHttp and create an activities that has a ListView with informations about the property.
this is a part of the JSON file

```
{
  "success": true,
  "response": [
    {
      "id": "h42zd7b9-1h67-42d0-ba0c-o4bf6987ae0f",
      "titre": "Belle maison fin 18e siècle",
      "description": "Maison de maitre du 18e siècle, entièrement rénovée avec soin. Belles prestations. Grand jardin arboré..",
      "nbPieces": 7,
      "caracteristiques": [
        "parking",
        "sauna",
        "garage"
      ],
      "prix": 457000,
      "ville": "Caen",
      "codePostal": "14000",
      "vendeur": {
        "id": "3e4r5t6y-eda4-44be-98b2-346af28d0dfa",
        "nom": "Romad",
        "prenom": "Patrick",
        "email": "p.romad@zilch.com",
        "telephone": "06.56.28.78.32"
      },
      "images": [
        "https:url/mock-api/images/m1.png",
        "https:url/mock-api/images/m2.png"
      ],
      "date": 1550091699
    }
```